# Running java code on Linux, and the code is written in IntelliJ in windows and CPLEX libraries are used, as well as I got input data from txt filex

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, cplex

I have a problem to run my java code on Linux. I wrote the code in IntelliJ on windows environment and it works. The code needs CPLEX libraries and I get data from txt files. Now, I want to run this code on Linux, but I got these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ilog/concert/IloException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ilog.concert.IloException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

I compiled the code first, and then run it. I do not know how can I run my code. Could you help me please?
for compiling the code I used this command:
`javac -classpath /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/lib/cplex.jar /home/../MIP_Case1/src/MIP.java`

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: what command did you use to run it on linux?

Comment: and does `ilog.concert.IloException` class part of `cplex.jar`? If so, I guess you forgot to add this library into classpath of a run command

Comment: @Flame239 I used many commands, first I went to the folder that Program_name.class is, and then write java Program_name. It caused those errors. I also used the commands in this website https://kunlei.github.io/cplex/cplex-java-setup/ which is java -Djava.library.path=/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux/ -classpath /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/lib/cplex.jar:/home/.../address of the main class

Comment: @Flame239 I edded cplex.jar as external library to my code and to its path.

Comment: I think you should stick to the official docs coming with your cplex distribution (e.g. try the steps from the page named `Setting up Eclipse for the Java API of CPLEX
`; yes this should generalize to your case as well). There will be an explicit Java + Linux part. I guess the core library will be needed on top of the Java API (e.g. libcplexXX.so).

Comment: @sascha I also added the path address to VM part in the run section of my IntellliJ code, but I got the same errors.